# Basic functionality related to CallerID in Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am new to Twilio.

I am sure it is an  excellent cloud based telephony product, but I am frustrated in getting some basic functionality in place.

I am trying to change the callerId while forwarding a call with a Twiml bin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>    
    callerId="+TwilioPhone"
    <Number>+MobilePhone2</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

In short I am trying to place a call to **TwilioPhone** using **MobilePhone1** and have the call forwarded to **MobilePhone2**. This part is working fine.

But I want the incoming call on **MobilePhone2** to have the caller id as **TwilioPhone**. This is just not working. The callerID showing up is that of **MobilePhone1** - which would have been okay if i was not using the callerID parameter.

I am going by the book (literally and as a metaphor), so where am i going wrong?

If anyone has had a similar experience and knows of a workaround or a solution to this problem, help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When adding attributes to XML elements, they need to reside within the tag itself. So, if you update your XML to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="+TwilioPhone">
    <Number>+MobilePhone2</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

then you should see the caller ID correctly.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for this! I feel like tearing my hair out! Lesson learnt